# Почему данный drag&drop лагает

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-n-drop

Реализовал у себя в проекте поддержку drag&drop функционала для элементов с классом `draggable`. К сожалению, данная реализация ведет сея иногда странно: элемент иногда начинает "убегать" от курсора и "застревает" при перемещении мышкой.

```js
//window.onload = function() {
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');

elements.forEach(function(el) {
  let mover = false,
    x, y, posx, posy, first = true;
  document.onmousedown = function() {
    mover = true;
  };
  document.onmouseup = function() {
    mover = false;
    first = true;
  };
  el.onmousemove = function(e) {
    el.style.cursor = "move";
    if (mover) {
      if (first) {
        x = e.offsetX;
        y = e.offsetY;
        first = false;
      }

      posx = e.pageX - x;
      posy = e.pageY - y;
      el.style.left = posx + 'px';
      el.style.top = posy + 'px';
    }
  }
});
//}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  overflow: auto;
  /* добавить полосу прокрутки */
}

header {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: white;
}

.wrap {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-link {
  padding: 1.1em;
}

.header-h1 {
  padding-left: 1em;
}

#header-title {
  color: #1c5a7d;
}

.header-link>a {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #888;
}

.header-link>a:hover {
  color: #444;
}

.header-menu-wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

header-h1 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 26px;
  float: right;
}

.botmaker-container {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.botmaker-node {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 230px;
  max-height: 130px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 120px;
  border-top-right-radius: 120px;
}

.node-form-input {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 170px;
}

.draggable {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100px;
}

.botmaker {
  min-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div id="header-title" class="">
      <h1 class="header-h1">Visual bot maker</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="header-menu-wrapper">
      <div class="wrapper-item header-link">
        <a href="">DOCUMENTATION</a>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper-item header-link">
        <a href="">FORUM</a>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper-item header-link">
        <a href="">SUPPORT</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<section class="botmaker-container dragscroll">
  <div class="botmaker">
    <div class="botmaker-node start-node draggable" style="cursor: move; left: 570px; top: 129px;">
      <form action="" method="post" class="form-group">
        <div class="node-form-input">
          <label for="startNode">Phrase</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="startNode" placeholder="Start phrase">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary node-submit">Ок</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Данные баги иногда не удается повторить, но они случаются. Может это не самая лучшая реализация и есть лучший пример drag&drop'a? или в моем случае какой то недочет мешает?

Comment: убегание от курсора лечится выравнивание элемента по центру относительно мыши. [Тут все расписано.](http://shpargalkablog.ru/2013/05/get-mouse-coordinates-inside-div.html)

Comment: @MishaSaidov выравнивать по центру при событии `onmousedown`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все дело в том, что `el.onmousemove` говорит о том, что блок будет перетаскиваться только тогда, когда мышь над ним, но если дернуть мышь резко, то элемент выйдет из под мыши и получаются эти самые лаги.

Этот код отслеживает положение мыши относительно родителя draggable элемента и ему не важно, под мышью ли он или нет.

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');

elements.forEach(function(el) {
  let mover = false,
    x, y, posx, posy, first = true;
  el.onmousedown = function() {
    mover = true;
  };
  el.onmouseup = function() {
    mover = false;
    first = true;
  };
  el.parentNode.onmousemove = function(e) {
    el.style.cursor = "move";
    if (mover) {
      if (first) {
        x = e.offsetX;
        y = e.offsetY;
        first = false;
      }

      posx = e.pageX - x;
      posy = e.pageY - y;
      el.style.left = posx + 'px';
      el.style.top = posy + 'px';
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: я еще сделал `el.parentNode.onmouseup` потому что ваш пример не работал после отжатия лкм без этой строчки)